# Do I need to call reset on the MediaPlayer before a release?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In the sample code for [RandomMusicPlayer](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/src/com/example/android/musicplayer/MusicService.html), `reset()` is called right before `release()`:

```
// stop and release the Media Player, if it's available
if (releaseMediaPlayer && mPlayer != null) {
    mPlayer.reset();
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}
```

Is this really necessary? Shouldn't the `release` take care of everything that would possibly need `reset`?

Answer (score 6):

Per the documentation, `release()` can be executed at any time. It is not necessary to call `reset()` first, nor is it necessary to set the player to `null` afterwards (GC should dispose of it in due time).

From the docs:

> After release(), the object is no longer available.

That said, I've ran into a few issues with MediaPlayer and its documentation. It's a very complex object to work with and tends to be a little buggy at times especially after throwing an error (with no explanation of the error code anywhere to be found!)

Comment: A's MediaPlayer is the worst piece of "art" ever created in the programming world. For example, connecting to a false url stream, the onError() is never called. Instead, you have to wait 31 seconds (!) for an IO exception. If you do not, the native part of the player will hang for the duration of the app session (at least on Samsung and LG devices that we have here). Reset() or release() does not help this catastrophe. Nor does setting it to null. You are stuck. The whole thing should be rewritten, together with EQ api which is equally bad and far, far too simple in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the release take care of everything that would possibly need reset?

Well, the `MediaPlayer` can be quite tricky. You need to understand the states that a MediaPlayer can be in and the calls that are allowed in those different states. The state diagram and valid/invalid states are here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram

The reason the code sample you provided calls `reset()` is just a defensive measure to uninitialize the `mediaPlayer` object to clean everything up properly. Strictly speaking, everything should be fine if you just call `release()`, but i'm not 100% sure about that.